# Outputting unicode from database (php)

Tags: php, unicode

Looking at other answers on stackoverflow I have put

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

at the top of my code, followed by

```
 mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'"); 
 mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 

 mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

with the business end of things:

```
echo ('<li>'. $value["businessName"]. ' | ');
echo htmlentities($value["coordinator"] , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo(" </li>");
```

However, for the output of

> ```
> Andy's Motors | Andrew Kavanagh
> Mo's Tavern | Móman Torés
> Whittlers | Joe Smith
> ```

The actual html produced is

```
<li> Andy's Motors | Andrew Kavanagh </li>
<li> Mo's Tavern | </li>
<li> Whittlers | Joe Smith </li>
```

The strings with unicode specific characters are empty.

Comment: I guess that `htmlentities()` fails. Have you already taken a look at its documentation and inspected the parameters you give it?